# Google Cloud Function On Update

Tags: java, google-cloud-functions

I want to save some values to GCS before updating an existing Cloud Function (using the CLI `deploy` command with the cloud function name). The value is of a static variable used in the function.

Is there an `onDestruction` hook (or something similar) that can be used when updating a Cloud Function? If not, please share your best bypass :)

Talking about 1st generation functions, written in Java.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no lifecycle event or trigger in v1 that runs when a Cloud Function or its container is last used.

You will have to store those values to GCS every time or after a certain number of calls.